# html5 audio FFT real-time canvas drawing without any animation or fade

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video, canvas

I want to get realtime fft frequency numbers on specific ranges of frequencies. It must be drawn into canvas without any animation/transition/fadeout effects, switching between frames. 
I found some scripts. like

https://github.com/wayou/HTML5_Audio_Visualizer

https://github.com/cwilso/AudioRecorder

I tried to adopt these scripts, but I didn't found the way to remove transitions between bars. I want bar to appear only if currenct level in current ms is "x", no slowly-fading-moving-down, and another animations.

It seems canvas don't support changing fillStyle of already created objects. 
I even tried to do it oldstyle without canvas, draw some bars and change opacity, but it don't work on top of video, having non-transparent border.

Using real mic input, as shown in second link, if you stop the sound, they all fading and moving down slowly... Is there any way to avoid this?

Maybe KineticJS will help?

Also, is it possible to lower buffer to minimum for mic input, to avoid delay of processing??

Please help!

Comment: The canvas does not store objects, it only know about pixels. The audio visualizer you referenced redraws the whole canvas every frame. It has extra code to smooth the levels as they drop, which can easily be removed. Look at the function `_drawSpectrum `in the source and modify the rendered frequency bars as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the answer. It was analyserNode.smoothingTimeConstant, which has high default value. I put it 0 and all went as I want!
Thanks!